# using rtf textbox control in MSWord VBA

Tags: vba

I have Windows 8.1, MSWord 365, Visual Basic for Application 7.1 and would like to use RTF Textbox control on a Userform. This control can not be seen in Controls windows nor can be found within Available Controls in Additional Controls windows. How can I use it?

Comment: MS Office apps don't come with a built-in RTF textbox (ask Microsoft why). Try to use the `InkEdit` controls. While these are ostensibly for a tablet (the cursor shows as a "dot"), I was able to add it easily to a user form in MS Word. In order to see the control, create a user form then using the VBE menu select Tools->Additional Controls, then scroll down to find "Microsoft InkEdit Control". This is not a complete solution - you'll have to add buttons/shortcuts for copy, paste, bold, italic, etc. But it's a start.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.